# Using custom button for ButtonBar's middleButton skin part

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I made a custom component, BitmapButton, which is based on spark.components.Button. It basically just takes three Bitmap objects - upBitmap, overBitmap and downBitmap - and then its skin class, BitmapButtonSkin, uses these bitmaps for each state.

Now the problem: I want to make a ButtonBar which uses my BitmapButton for its buttons. What do you think would be the right way to approach this? Do I need to create a new component such as ToggleBitmapButton and then its skin or can I reuse the classes I've already made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need only create a custom skin for the ButtonBar and inside it use custom skins for the buttons.  From what you have described as your goal, I see no need to create custom components, neither for the ButtonBar, nor for the buttons themselves.

Comment: I created a custom component BitmapButton so that I could write the MXML `<BitmapButton upImage="..." overImage="..." downImage="..."/>`.

Comment: @Omer - Ah, okay. I guess that makes sense if you know that you're going to reuse it for more than, say, three buttons, and/or you want to load or even change those images dynamically.

The ButtonBar, nevertheless should work with only changing the skin.